# Active Model Serializer use no serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, activemodel, active-model-serializers

At times I'd like to use no serializer for a model, and other times I do.  I have tried to request `nil` serializer, but it seems that a serializer is used regardless.

```
class API::FinancialDashboardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name, :weeks_remaining

    has_many :check_ins, serializer: nil
end
```

In this instance I'd like to return the association **without** any serializer, but it still uses the `CheckInSerializer` anyway.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just do:

```
class API::FinancialDashboardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :check_ins, :id, :name, :weeks_remaining
end
```

Or if that doesn't work:

```
class API::FinancialDashboardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :check_ins, :id, :name, :weeks_remaining

  def check_ins
    object.check_ins.map(&:as_json)
  end
end
```

Comment: I was trying to change the key name of an array of strings with `ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new` but was facing `No serializer found for resource` error. Your second option solved my problem. Thanks.